# Why I can't connect Quarkus application to Keycloak with custom certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keycloak, quarkus

As [this issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12442) My keycloak does not have a trusted certificate, so i put the property `quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none`

Even so, it is unable to perform the request!!!

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried to add the custom CA Root certifate `ca.crt` when I build the image with:

```
      gradle build -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true \
      -Dquarkus.container-image.group=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE -x test \
      -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args=-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/certs/ca.crt,-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

but with no luck!

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `quarkus.oidc-client.tls.verification=none`

This option is related to the quarkus-oidc-client extension and it disables the verification of the authenticity of the server's SSL/TLS certificate as well.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.